# find | sed - regex matching apostrophe instead of full stop in search phrase

Tags: regex, sed, find

Got this really odd thing happening with a search and replace script I am trying to implement. The following command...

```
find './files' -type f \( -iname "*.js" \) -exec sed -i '' s/\$stateProvider.state\(\'app\./\$stateProvider.state\(\'app.myap\./ {} +
```

Is matching `$stateProvider.state('app'`

When it should only be matching `$stateProvider.state('app.'` <-- you can see that when the full stop is missing it should not match (since it is included in the matching pattern).

Comment: Try this `sed`: `sed -i '' "s/\$stateProvider\.state\('app\./\$stateProvider.state('app.myap./" {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises from the fact that you have not quoted the `sed` code. As a result, all the escapes are interpreted by the the shell. So the `\.` that you have included, is interpreted by the the shell to be a plain `.` and that's what `sed` sees. This is why `sed` matches it with any character. You can see what `sed` sees by typing the following in your shell:

```
$ echo s/\$stateProvider.state\(\'app\./\$stateProvider.state\(\'app.myap\./
s/$stateProvider.state('app./$stateProvider.state('app.myap./
```

or just try this:

```
$ echo \.
.
```

So you need to escape the escape character, i.e.

```
$ echo \\.
\.
```

**Edit**: To find the complete command, you have to think backwards. The command that we want to send to sed is the following:

```
s/\$stateProvider\.state('app\./$stateProvider.state('app.myap./
```

Notice that I have escaped the characters `$` and `.` because they have special meaning in sed when used in the pattern. Now I have to escape the above string again, but bash (or whatever shell) this time:

```
s/\\\$stateProvider\\.state\(\'app\\./\$stateProvider.state\(\'app.myap\./
```

Notice that I have escaped the characters `\`, `$`, `(`, and `'` because they have special meaning in bash.

So the complete command would be

```
sed -i '' s/\\\$stateProvider\\.state\(\'app\\./\$stateProvider.state\(\'app.myap\./
```

Alternatively, for the last step, I could have simply used quoting:

```
's/\$stateProvider\.state('\''app\./$stateProvider.state('\''app.myap./'
```

Notice that I only had to take special care for `'`, which has to be written as `'\''` inside single quotes.

Comment: So why don't I need to double slash all escaped (regex) characters if the sed shell is stripping them away ?

Comment: @Exitos I expanded on my answer.